# Populate a Dropdown list With SQL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, t-sql, drop-down-menu, ado.net

i have a DropDownList in my asp.net website but i can not get it to populate with data from my sql server.

am i missing something?

```
Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection  
Dim sqCmd As New SqlCommand       
Dim sqlreader As SqlDataReader    

sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = .......;Database=......;User ID=....
Password=...." 

sqCmd.Connection = sqlconn
sqlconn.Open()
sqCmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT CompanyDivision FROM Reports"
sqlreader = sqCmd.ExecuteReader()

DropDownList.DataSource = sqlreader
DropDownList.DataTextField = "CompanyDivision"
DropDownList.DataValueField = "CompanyDivision"
DropDownList.DataBind()

sqlreader.Close()
sqlconn.Close()
```

Comment: DataSource must be an IEnumerable type, you can't use a Reader. Fill a DataSet and bind to it.

Comment: Hi, do you have an example on how to do that in my code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way of attaching a sql query to a dropdown is through the use of a `SqlDataSource` in the aspx.

You can do it like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" 
                   ID="CompanyDivisionSource"
                   DataSourceMode="DataReader"
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourConnectionStringKey%>"
                   SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT CompanyDivision FROM Reports" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="CompanyDivisionSource" 
                  DataTextField="CompanyDivision"
                  DataValueField="CompanyDivision" />
```

I recommend the use of that expression for the connection string also. You need to place your connection string on the web.config file, under the `<connectionStrings>` tag. You will them be able to reuse the same connection across many pages without having to hardcode it on every use.

More about the `SqlDataSource` can be found on [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz12d98w(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the recommendation and yes i will move my connection string to the webconfig file to reuse it for all my pages.

i can use the ">" and add "Choose a datasource" then go thru the "wizard" but i would rather like to code it.

The way you showed me i guess is in the asp(x) site and not in the dropdown Object (double clicked on the object) where i would like to put the code.

is there just something missing in my code or do i have to redo it from scratch?

Thanks

Comment: When you double click something it's probably opening the visual designer for you. For each page, you have two files: the codebehind file (.cs) and the markup file (.aspx). When you click with the right mouse button on the aspx file, you can choose to view the markup or the designer. I really recommend you always try to use the markup, as it really helps in understanding how everything works. In this sample, you will probably use markup only, and remove all of your code from the code behind. This code style on the markup is sometimes defined as "declarative code", and is usually more concise.

Comment: Hi, 
Yes i see the 2 pages default.aspx and default.aspx.vb every time i do code i usually do everything in my aspx.vb file (rather then my markup file).

But i see you point.

This will problem work easiest(and best) with the sample you gave for DropDownLists Thank you again.